# Javascript for loop post form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, loops, submit

The for loop runs through data (json) from the facebook api.
Now i would like to put the fb data in my own database (for usage in other sites)

The problem is not with reading the data, but somewhere in the submit
It looks like i'm only able to submit 1 time
I think that theForm[x] is the problem.

The code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : ***, // App ID
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });



  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load
      FB.login(function() {
   // handle the response

        }, {scope: 'friends_relationships,friends_relationship_details,friends_photos,friends_about_me,user_about_me,friends_hometown,friends_location'});

    } else {

      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login(function() {
   // handle the response
        }, {scope: 'friends_relationships,friends_relationship_details,friends_photos,friends_about_me,user_about_me,friends_hometown,friends_location'});

        }
  });
  };


 // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));



  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
   var $tokenx =   $(FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken']);
     printTable($tokenx.selector);
    };




    function printTable(token){

    FB.api('/me?fields=name,gender,friends.fields(relationship_status,name,gender,location,picture.width(200).height(200))', function(myList) {



        var theForm = [];
         for (var x = 0 ; x < myList.friends.data.length ; x++){
         console.log(myList.friends.data[x].id + myList.friends.data[x].name);
        // postPage(myList.friends.data[x].id, myList.friends.data[x].name);
         var newInput1, newInput2;
  // Start by creating a <form>
  theForm[x] = document.createElement('form');
  theForm[x].id = x;
  theForm[x].name = x;
  theForm[x].target = "hiddenFrame";
  theForm[x].action = "insert.php";
  theForm[x].method = 'post';
  // Next create the <input>s in the form and give them names and values
  newInput1 = document.createElement('input');
  newInput1.type = 'text';
  newInput1.name = 'id';
  newInput1.value = myList.friends.data[x].id;
  newInput2 = document.createElement('input');
  newInput2.type = 'text';
  newInput2.name = 'naam';
  newInput2.value = myList.friends.data[x].name;
  // Now put everything together...
  theForm[x].appendChild(newInput1);
  theForm[x].appendChild(newInput2);

  theForm[x].submit();
  //document.getElementById(theForm[x]).submit();

         }
         }
            }
            )};



/*          
 function postPage (id2,naam2) {
  var theForm, newInput1, newInput2;
  // Start by creating a <form>
  theForm = document.createElement('form');
  theForm.target = "hiddenFrame";
  theForm.action = "insert.php";
  theForm.method = 'post';
  // Next create the <input>s in the form and give them names and values
  newInput1 = document.createElement('input');
  newInput1.type = 'text';
  newInput1.name = 'id';
  newInput1.value = id2;
  newInput2 = document.createElement('input');
  newInput2.type = 'text';
  newInput2.name = 'naam';
  newInput2.value = naam2;
  // Now put everything together...
  theForm.appendChild(newInput1);
  theForm.appendChild(newInput2);

  theForm.submit();
alert(id2 + " - " + naam2);
};
*/

</script>
<iframe src="insert.php" name="hiddenFrame"></iframe>

<form method="post" action="insert.php" target="hiddenFrame">
naam<input type="text" name="naam"><br>
id<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The insert.php looks like (removed database connection "host","user","pass","table"):

```
<?php
$db=mysql_connect("host","user","pass")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("table",$db);

$id = $_POST[id];
$naam = $_POST[naam];
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM USERS WHERE ID='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = $result['count'];

echo $count;
echo " - ";
echo $id;


if($count > 0){
   //found

}else{
   $sql="INSERT INTO USERS(ID,NAME)VALUES('$id','$naam')";
    mysql_query($sql,$db);
}

mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Sorry for the long code, but i didn't think partial was possible
Again I think that theForm[x] is the problem but i couldn't find it.

Already thanks if someone could point me in the right direction.

Ps. I know I have messy code :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
theForm[x].submit();
```

**.submit()** is like a **click on the submit button.**

*So what happens in your script:*

1. *for* Loop begins. (x = 0)
2. Creates Form[0]
3. Creates all Input fields and fills them with values
4. **Submits** the form (*aka POST to insert.php*) and **"breaks"** the *for* Loop.

Instead user jQuery's **$.post** from. It should look like this:

```
$.post('insert.php', {id: myList.friends.data[x].id, naam: myList.friends.data[x].name}, function(data){
    // handle response here if required
});
```

If you get problems with duplicate posts/values, its probably because the $.post Request is asynchronous.

Have a look at this page for information on how to perform syncronous requests ...
**http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/**

Comment: Thanks for the example with the button

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have only the first element of *myList* recorded in the database. That's because once you call *.submit()* your for loop is skipped and the page is refreshed. I'll suggest to avoid the usage of forms and just use simple ajax requests made with jQuery (I saw that you are already using it) -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: does submit() stop the loop completely? Never knew that. I read online that using a iframe is neccesary because otherwise the page refresses. But i will try the ajax jquery method!

Comment: You actually forward the user to another page. So, yes the for loop is skipped.